# Editing Registry Key Error

Tags: ruby, windows

I am trying to create a registry key called foo if it doesn't exist, if it does exist I am trying to read its value. If value >0 I am trying to decrement it by one as a way to track trial uses of a piece of software, but I am getting this error:

```
$ ruby _RUNME.rb
no key exists
c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:261:in `call': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:261:in `CreateKey'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:412:in `create'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:503:in `create'
    from _RUNME.rb:18:in `rescue in <main>'
    from _RUNME.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

My code is:

```
begin
Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.open('SOFTWARE\foo') do |reg|
    value = reg['foo'] 
    if(value.to_i>0)
        reg['foo'] = value.to_i-1
    else 
        puts "no trial uses left"
        sleep(10) 
        Kernel.exit(false)
    end
end 
rescue
    puts "no key exists"
      Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.create("software\\foo","Win32::Registry::KEY_ALL_ACCESS")
    Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.open('SOFTWARE\foo') do |reg|
    reg['foo']="55" 
    puts "wrote new key foo with value 55"
end
end
```

using Ruby version 2.0.0

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: added log details as requested.